# Avoid table name "prefix" in session.query result

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using a query in SQLAlchemy like this :

```
conn = engine.connect()
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=conn)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
session = Session() 

select = session.query(reflected_table1,reflected_table2).join(reflected_table2,reflected_table1.c.id == reflected_table2.c.id).filter(all_filters).yield_per(1000)
```

(all_filters are predefined filters I've constructed previously)

But I'm getting the results as so :

```
{u'reflected_table1_subState': 'no', u'reflected_table2_severity': '3_major', u'reflected_table2_isDuplicate': None, u'reflected_table2_releaseName': 'i1', u'reflected_table1_TSsubmitOn': None,...
```

How can I avoid having the name of the table prefixing the column name in the results??

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need it as a dictionary? The following would work (query line simplified):

```
 result = session.query(reflected_table1,reflected_table2).....
 for row in result:
     row.subState
     row.severity
```